# Is this Leanan sídhe homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, races

Leanan sídhe are fae in Irish myth that gave inspiration to artists, poets and writers. Those gifted by her became famous and renowned. The caveat was that they were often driven to fall madly in love with her and murdered.

I'm wondering if this race is balanced or not.

- Ability Score Increase: Your Charisma increases by 2 and your Wisdom increases by 1.
- Darkvision: You have superior vision in dark and dim conditions. You can see in dim light within 60 feet of you as if it were bright light, and in darkness as if it were dim light. You can't discern color in darkness, only shades of gray.
- Fey: Your creature type is fey rather than humanoid.
- Otherworldly Inspiration: You have 4 Otherworldly Inspiration dice, each one of which is a d6. You regain all dice when you finish a long rest.
- Fey Charm: As an action you can force a creature to make a Wisdom saving throw. If the creature fails, it becomes charmed by you for one minute, during which you have to Concentrate as if on a spell. The spell ends early if you or any of your allies deal damage to the creature. While charmed in this way, a creature can do nothing but use its movement to approach you in a safe manner. It stops moving when it's 5 feet away from you, instead it just stares at you and listens to your voice. Using this ability costs you two Otherworldly Inspiration dice.
- Dark Muse: As a reaction when a creature that can hear you makes an ability check, you can roll one of your Otherworldly Inspiration dice and add the number to the results of the Creature's ability check. The Otherworldly Inspiration dice rolled is expended.

Comment: You may wish to review our guidance on [asking homebrew review questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/52137). Specifically what I would love to see added is what your goals are (what you want this race to do/feel like/emulate) and why you give it the traits you did.

Comment: Oh and of course: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: You have mixed class features with racial features in this homebrew. Please revise this to make it align with racial features that can be found in the Players Handbook.  Explicitly, having a dice pool is the kind of thing that is not a racial feature if you compare it to all of the other races in the PHB.  Then, a fair balance comparison can be made. (In other words, you are asking us to try and compare a slice of bacon to a spatula  - not using a 'like for like' basis)

Comment: All I did was copy and paste it.  Usually, if someone asks for clarification or more detail, as Someone_Evil did, adding in what they are asking for into the question is the best practice.  Comments eventually go away.  It's one of the ways that we are different from a discussion forum.

Comment: How is the DC calculated for Fey Charm? Is it your intent to have the feature work on all creatures or just humanoids?

Comment: Forgot about the DC, it's supposed to be 8+proficiency +Cha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the [detect balance spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vq1kz6PRAbw5LHy6amH-bNb4OuB8DBXL1RsZROt03Sc/edit#gid=0) for this.

> CHA +2, WIS +1: 12 points
> Darkvision 60: 3 points
> Not A Humanoid: 2 points

There's not anything like Dark Muse on the spreadsheet, but I decided that this was a 4-point feature because the character will always be able to use it four times per long rest (and will apply it to the four most important skill checks anyone makes).  Note that this is the same price as "advantage on a common roll".

Fey Charm isn't on the spreadsheet, but we can model it as being similar to Charm Person 2/day.  Note that Charm Person is a bit worse, because it gives the creature advantage if you or your allies are fighting it.  (I recommend that you add this to your class feature as well; if you don't, we should charge more points for this feature.) You also might consider whether this should be restricted to humanoids only. An L1 spell twice per day is worth 6 points.

Fey Charm and Dark Muse draw from the same dice pool, so they have anti-synergy; the spreadsheet tells us that we halve the cost of the cheaper ability.  So:

> Fey Charm: 6 points
> Dark Muse: +2 points

The total is 25 points which is exactly right.

Note that this race, as you have it listed, is missing some of the traits we usually associate with the fey.  In particular the spreadsheet has a two-point item called "Fey Ancestry (advantage vs charm, can't sleep)" which you probably want to add here.

---

Commenters have suggested that the dice pool mechanic makes this "more like a class feature than a racial feature".  That's not false, but I don't see it as a problem -- it just means that it's slightly more tricky to identify if it's balanced because there aren't as good things to compare it to.  Someone else looking at this race might decide that Dark Muse was more like an 8-point power than a 4-point power, and it would be hard to really know for sure.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. What do you think of the sentiment that this race includes class features and that it's features should be made to align with the features of pre-existing races?